# ExtJS 2.2 - Getting values of a checkbox group

Tags: javascript, extjs

I would like to get the comma separated values of checkboxes checked in a checkbox group. The latest version of ExtJS has a simple getValue defined to get this value.

But i am using an old version of ExtJS - 2.2 - http://www.senchaexperts.com/api/extjs2.2/

Using Ext.form.CheckboxGroup class to create checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override the Ext.form.ChecboxGroup class and create a custom getValue() method. Follow this link to view exactly how to do this 
    : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?39161-2.1svn-2.2-Checkbox-RadioGroup-getName-getValue-return-nothing-isFormField-true